# len(str) giving wrong result after retrieving str from filename

Tags: python-3.x

Any idea why I am getting a length of 6 instead of 5?
I created a file called björn-100.png and ran the code using python3:

```
import os

for f in os.listdir("."):
    p = f.find("-")
    name = f[:p]
    print("name")
    print(name)
    length = len(name)
    print(length)
    for a in name:
        print(a)
```

prints out the following:

```
name
björn
6
b
j
o
̈
r
n
```

instead of printing out

```
name
björn
5
b
j
ö
r
n
```

Comment: Obviously because it treats the umlaut & the o as distinct characters.  What encoding is the string using?

Comment: Print out the type of the string.  It looks like it isnt unicode, so it just splits it apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get the correct string with the two dots inside the o char is:

```
import unicodedata

name = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', name)
```

Comment: Ah.. funny that I only noticed that you posted this answer after I edited mine. Glad you figured it out. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using python 2.7, you can simply decode the file name as UTF-8 first:

```
length = len(name.decode('utf-8'))
```

But since you're using python 3 and can't simply decode a `string` as if it were a `bytearray`, I recommend using [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) to normalize the string.

```
import unicodedata
length = len(unicodedata.normalize('NFC', name))
```

Comment: Did you try this? It gives the error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. The type of f is str and the type of name is str

Comment: I did, but I'm using python 2.7 and only just noticed that you're using python 3, in which case `decode` is only available to `bytearray` or `bytes`. The problem is that you're reading the path names as strings when they really are bytes. For python 3 I recommend normalizing the string using the [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) instead. See my updated answer for usage.

Comment: Well your answer of length = len(name.decode('utf-8')) does not solve the problem using python 2.7 either. The decode call does not crash like it does in python 3, but it doesn't solve the length problem of the string. The length is still 6, not 5.